# Backbone.js - get childElementCount value in devTools to print

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, children, document-body

I trying to log `childElementCount` property in chrome dev tools but I get undefined.

this is my code:

```
console.log('childElementCount---', this.ui.tbody.get('childElementCount')
```

returns `childElementCount--- undefined`

why is it undefined?

[image: img1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) is for retrieving the underlying DOM element from the jQuery object. It accepts an integer index instead of a string. 
Try `this.ui.tbody.get(0).childElementCount` or `this.ui.tbody.get(0).getAttribute('childElementCount')`

or withjQuery:

`this.ui.tbody.prop('childElementCount')` 
 or `this.ui.tbody.children().length`